# GUI tool for monitoring java process

Tags: linux, java, gui

I want a gui tool to monitor each java process its memory, cpu usage and others.

so can anyone suggest me some tools?

Answer (score 2):

You might find [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) fits your requirements, especially with some of the [plugins](https://visualvm.github.io/plugins.html) (Visual GC in particular).

VisualVM can monitor CPU and memory use, and can also profile code running on the JVM. With Visual GC you also get detailed GC monitoring.

To download and start VisualVM, on distributions where it isn’t packaged:

```
wget https://github.com/visualvm/visualvm.src/releases/download/1.3.9/visualvm_139.zip
unzip visualvm_139.zip
cd visualvm_139
./bin/visualvm
```

On Debian and derivatives, where it is packaged:

```
apt install visualvm
visualvm
```

If you want to monitor a JVM running on a remote system, there is a better approach than trying to run a GUI on the remote system: you can start `jstatd` on the remote system, run VisualVM on your local system and connect to the remote system’s `jstatd` instance. See [Working with remote applications](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/applications_remote.html) in the VisualVM documentation for details. Be aware that `jstatd` isn’t secure, so you should be careful (read its documentation for some workarounds).

Comment: yes I have followed the steps and when I run visualvm it says "/visualvm_139/platform/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set" and shell terminates

Comment: You need to actually be running in a GUI for this to work, or if you’re connecting using SSH, forward the display (`ssh -Y` or `ssh -X`).

Comment: how to use this command I have tried with ssh -X xx.xx.xx.xx but it is not working

Comment: You’ll have to bit a bit more specific — what exactly isn’t working?

Comment: I have updated "/etc/ssh/ssh_config file" and I have set yes to ForwardX11 and then I tried to open this server using putty and I have enabled X11 forwarding and I set X display location as localhost:0.0. After that I launch visualvm it says "error can't open display"

Comment: Ah, you’re connecting from Windows! You need to run an X server on your Windows system, such as [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

Comment: You’ll no doubt find it easier to use `jstatd` on the server and run VisualVM on your Windows machine instead, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) for getting GUI interface of java process internals.

JConsole is part of Java JDK package/kit and it's located in JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: Thanks is gui available for jconsole in linux environment

Comment: @wazza, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Java Mission Control: jmc commnad , one of the best  feature is Flight Recoder which can profile your application nearly without an overhead.

Comment: Watch out for the license requirements on JMC and FR...